# How to interpret scientific notation?

Tags: notation, scientific-notation

I'm having a problem understanding scientific notation. What is the difference between the following:

$$\text{5e2, 5e-2, -5e2, -5e-2}$$

Comment: $x \, e \, y = x \cdot 10^y$.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
5e2 & = 5\times 10^2 = 500 \\
5e{-2} & = 5\times 10^{-2} = 0.05 \\
-5e2 & = -5\times 10^2 = -500 \\
-5e{-2} &  = -5 \times 10^{-2} = -0.05
\end{align}

Answer (score -4):

[image][This image should help hopefully.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WG2E.png)

Comment: Plese type your answer and use MathJax to render the math instead of pictures that aren't searchable. Thank you.